# Pandas DataFrame get column combined max values

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a pandas DataFrame like following.

`df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [3,1,2,4,5,3,4,10], "B": [1,3,2,4,0,0,1,0]})`

The row values 0 to 10 are recommendations (10 is best). One DataFrame column is a category (A, B, etc.) the 0 to 10 recommendation is related to. All categories have the **same weight** but each row is related to one item.

I want the DataFrame to be sorted for items with the max values combined to **both** (or more) categories. So if a row related to an item has a value of 10 in category A but value 0 in category B, that would not be the expected solution for the highest rated item. In example given above the row with values [4,4] would be the best choice.

My groupby solution does not give the expected result.

```
grouped = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])
grouped[["A", "B"]].max().sort(ascending=False)
```

result:

```
        A   B
A   B       
10  2   10  0
5   0   5   0
4   4   4   4
    1   4   1
3   1   3   1
    0   3   0
2   2   2   2
1   3   1   3
```

A row based total sum would also not yield the expected result since it does not differentiate between categories.

Comment: why is `[4,4]` the best choice?

Comment: because for both columns combined it has the max values. Last row for example has 10 in col A but 0 in col B. And for col B there are other, higher values. You could say I am seeking for the combined mean max of both columns. Hope this clarifies

Comment: What is the correct total order?

Comment: The values are random numbers and since I am not sure how to calculate it I do not have the correct total order. Thank you for the pandas rank hint. I left my rank approach as a comment below @dermen's answer which in fact does not reproduce the same sequence order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [3,1,2,4,5,3,4,10], "B": [1,3,2,4,0,0,1,0]})
```

then calculate the rank for each column in the data frame

```
rank = df.rank(method = "dense")
rank

Out[44]:
    A   B
0   3   2
1   1   4
2   2   3
3   4   5
4   5   1
5   3   1
6   4   2
7   6   1
```

add a new column to the data frame which is the the total rank based on all categories

```
df['total_rank'] = rank.sum(axis = 1)
df


Out[46]:
    A   B   total_rank
0   3   1   5
1   1   3   5
2   2   2   5
3   4   4   9
4   5   0   6
5   3   0   4
6   4   1   6
7   10  0   7
```

and finally sort your data frame by total rank

```
df.sort(columns='total_rank' , ascending = False)


Out[49]:
    A   B   total_rank
3   4   4   9
7   10  0   7
4   5   0   6
6   4   1   6
0   3   1   5
1   1   3   5
2   2   2   5
5   3   0   4
```

Comment: Thank you! The sequence order seems to be correct from my perspective. I liked the approach from @dermen though. How would I modify this in case category A has more weight compared to category B? Just A*2 (e.g. A has two times higher weight than B)?

Comment: You can calculate the rank normally for group A and then multiply by the weight

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
df['pos'] = df.A/df.A.mean() + df.B/df.B.mean()
df.sort( columns='pos', ascending=False)

#    A  B       pos
#3   4  4  3.909091
#7  10  0  2.500000
#1   1  3  2.431818
#2   2  2  1.954545
#6   4  1  1.727273
#0   3  1  1.477273
#4   5  0  1.250000
#5   3  0  0.750000
```

If you have more columns you want to rank `['A','B','C', ...]`

```
cols = ['A','B'] # ,'C', 'D', ... ]
df['pos'] = pandas.np.sum([ df[col]/df[col].mean() for col in cols ],axis=0)
```

## Update

Because 0 is considered a quality value (lowest), I would amend my answer as follows (not sure it makes a huge difference)

```
df['pos'] = (df.A+1)/(df.A.max()+1) + (df.B+1)/(df.B.max()+1)
df.sort( columns='pos', ascending=False)
#    A  B       pos
#3   4  4  1.454545
#7  10  0  1.200000
#1   1  3  0.981818
#2   2  2  0.872727
#6   4  1  0.854545
#0   3  1  0.763636
#4   5  0  0.745455
#5   3  0  0.563636
```

Comment: Looks good to me. After receiving the "rank" hint by @padraic-cunningham    I came up with `df["best_choice"] = df[["A", "B"]].rank().sum(axis=1)` and `df.sort("best_choice", ascending=False)` but it yields in a different sequence order while [4,4] still seems to be the best choice.

Comment: I am not sure exactly how ```DataFrame.rank``` works on multiple columns, and I cannot reproduce that result using any alternative method...  the way I see it, there are 11 values for 'A' and 5 values for 'B'. Therefore (A=4,B=4) corresponds to rank 5/11 for A and rank 5/5 for B,  adding the two yields a total rank of 1.45 (the max total rank). Next we consider (A=10, B=0), corresponding to rank 11/11 for A and 1/5 for B. Adding the two yields 1.2, the net highest value etc. Am I correct to add the individual  rankings, or is total rank more complex ?